# Simulating Plasma Ionization Rate using PPT formula

Tags: laser, ionization-energy

I've used A.14 formula in the paper ["Ultrashort filaments of light in weakly-ionized, optically-transparent media"](https://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0612063#:%7E:text=Ultrashort%20filaments%20of%20light%20in%20weakly%2Dionized%2C%20optically%2Dtransparent%20media,-L.&text=Modern%20laser%20sources%20nowadays%20deliver,exceeding%20several%20terawatt%20(TW).) to calculate the dependence of ionization rate in oxygen molecules in air on laser intensity.
I'm interested in comparing it with the famous $\sigma_kI^k$ law of MPI ionization.

However, there is something wrong in the simple simulation I wrote, since the ionization rate in PPT using is much higher than we expect.
Do you have a caveat for why is it happening?

Here is the python code I wrote:
https://github.com/IvanOstr/Ionization-PPT/blob/main/ionization_rate_PPT.py

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be the z_eff value I chose.
Instead of choosing it for Oxygen atom which is 8 - 6 = 2 you should choose it for an Oxygen molecule. However, seems like no one have a theoretical estimate for it and the measured one seems to be z_eff = 0.53 according to this [article](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0030401899001133).